# Use hotkeys with function keys, modifier keys, and a letter keys

Tags: autohotkey

How can I use a hotkey that responds to pressing **F24 & Shift D**, for example? I want to press a function key (F#, not the key that is labeled "fn"), a modifier key, and a letter.

I am using a mouse with multiple side buttons; I'm using G Hub to send F24 when one of the mouse buttons is pressed. So I'm trying to have that mouse button act as another modifier key.

I'm able to do assign a hotkey with only F24 and a letter key. But I no matter what I try, I cannot do this with an added modifier key. When I try to run the script, I get the error "invalid key." I have tried this with the **Shift** key and with the **Alt** key, and neither will work.

This works:

```
F24 & D::MsgBox, hello
```

I've tried every alternat syntax shown in the documentation, but none of the following work.

```
F24 & {Alt} & D::MsgBox, hello
!{F42}D::
!{F42} & D::
F24 & ! & D::
{Alt} {F24} D::
F24 & +D::
```

Comment: How do you generate F24? Do you have a keyboard with 24 F keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combinations of 3 or more hotkeys [are not supported](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) as described in the documentation you can use `#if` and `GetKeyState`

I don't know how are you generating F24 the following will work if you first press shift and then F12 and d if your keyboard generates F24 just replace F12 with F24

```
#if GetKeyState("Shift", "P")
F12 & d::MsgBox works
#If
```